# Removing periodic noise from an image using the Fourier Transform

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering, signal-processing, fft

I am performing the 2D FFT on a particular image and I get its spectral components. Now this image has been superimposed with another image to create periodic noise.

The original image as well as the periodic noise version is shown below:

## Original Image

[image]

## Periodic Noise Image

[image]

To filter this out, I used manual boxes that masked the components in the magnitude spectrum that are quite large relative to the other components as shown below.

[image]

After this is done, I perform an inverse FFT, but I do not get the original image back.

[image]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code that masks the values and then proceeds to do an inverse 2D FFT on the masked spectral image:

```
pat1 = imread('Pattern1.png');

spec_orig = fft2(double(pat1));     
spec_orig2 = abs(spec_orig); 
spec_img = fftshift(spec_orig2);

for j = 115:125
    for n = 96:106
        spec_img(n,j) = 0; 
    end
    for n = 216:226
        spec_img(n,j) = 0; 
    end
    for n = 274:284
        spec_img(n,j) = 0; 
    end
    for n = 298:308
        spec_img(n,j) = 0; 
    end
    for n = 12:22
        spec_img(n,j) = 0; 
    end
    for n = 37:47
        spec_img(n,j) = 0; 
    end
end

%Getting Back the Image for Pattern1
figure;subplot(2,1,1);
spec_img = log(1 + spec_img);
imshow(spec_img,[]); 

subplot(2,1,2);
ptnfx = ifft2(spec_img);
imshow(ptnfx);
```

Comment: That double for loop at the beginning can be removed by making use of array indexing: `spec_img([96:106 216:226],115:125)=0` etc.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Wasn't aware that you could do that - thank you!

Comment: No problem. This is why I suggested getting familiar with matlab itself:) Having a firm grasp on the essentials of the language can make your life much easier, and your code much more elegant and efficient.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala I've taken the liberty to improve the flow of your question.  This is a great question and I'd like that it be a good example of a MATLAB question/answer for the record books.  Thanks for asking a great question!

Comment: @rayryeng no problem, I was about to delete the question as it was being downvoted, but I guess that wasn't the case.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala please leave the question intact.  With the edits I made, it's now an even higher quality question :)  Also, you only got 1 downvote... there are 2 upvotes.  That's a win!  There will be more coming.  Don't worry :)... and I hope that the person who downvoted will remove his/her downvote because of the edits I made.

Comment: @rayryeng I've had a fair few people say that my MATLAB questions are too broad, but outside the MATLAB Central forum, I don't think a lot of people have asked questions about image processing

Comment: Did you ask questions in the MATLAB Central forum where they said it was too broad or here?  This question is certainly not too broad.  You showed us what you tried and where you got stuck.  This is highly appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: BTW, you can certainly continue to ask image processing questions :D. I'm the only one of two people who have the gold badge in that tag so it's a testament to how much I like the area.

Comment: @rayryeng People have been saying it's too broad for SO. I would have asked M Central, but I believe that SO is the future of APIs and coding references. Yes! Thank you! I believe I'm mostly done with this assignment as of this question - but this assignment leads to an image processing *internship*, so expect more of me here.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala Ah I understand.  It's a pity I wasn't around before those questions got closed.  I would have answered them.  In any case, I'm looking forward to your further questions.  Good luck at your internship!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96728/discussion-between-sharan-duggirala-and-rayryeng).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Filtering in the frequency domain is a tricky business to get right.  Your code has a few errors that are preventing you from reconstructing the original image:

1. You are applying the filtering **on the magnitude component only**.  You have to do this on the **original image spectrum**, not just the magnitude component.  The phase is essential for proper reconstruction.  BTW, to coin a signal processing term, what you are implementing is a [notch filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band-stop_filter) or a band-stop filter, which removes certain select frequencies.
2. You centered the spectrum via `fftshift` but after you filtered you **forgot to undo the shift**.  You must invoke `ifftshift` on your resulting filtered image to undo the centering.
3. You're finding the inverse FFT of the **log-transformed** image.  Remember that performing a log transform of the spectrum is *only for display* purposes.  You **do not** use this when filtering or finding the inverse.  Doing this will give you unintended consequences as the majority of the spectrum has been changed due to a non-linear operation.  You have to do it on the original image spectrum itself.
4. A minor note, but make sure you call `real` after you filter the result after you take the inverse FFT.  There are most likely some residual imaginary components that are due to computational floating-point errors and so calling `real` will only extract the real components of the signal.

With these corrections, this is the code I have. I've read your image directly from StackOverflow to be reproducible:

```
pat1 = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIumJ.png');

%// Change
spec_orig = fft2(double(pat1)); 
spec_img = fftshift(spec_orig);

for j = 115:125
    for n = 96:106
        spec_img(n,j) = 0; 
    end
    for n = 216:226
        spec_img(n,j) = 0; 
    end
    for n = 274:284
        spec_img(n,j) = 0; 
    end
    for n = 298:308
        spec_img(n,j) = 0; 
    end
    for n = 12:22
        spec_img(n,j) = 0; 
    end
    for n = 37:47
        spec_img(n,j) = 0; 
    end
end

%// Change
ptnfx = real(ifft2(ifftshift(spec_img)));
imshow(ptnfx,[]);
```

I get this image:

[image]

A pretty good reconstruction of the original image I'll add. You'll still see a bit of streaking and that is highly dependent on the notch filter shape and size.  Perhaps make the size bigger and even more so, make the shape of the notch filter circular instead of square.  This has a tendency to preserve more of the original image as hard edges introduced by the corners of the squares have unintended ringing effects.

Comment: that was a rather silly error. My updated result is now poted on the question. Does this pertain to the same question? If not I'm happy to accept this as the answer.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala take a look at my comment above.  I'd be happy to help you debug this problem, but I need to know more about how you got that transform - where's the original image? Where's the code you used to transform your image?

Comment: Can you upload the **original** image?... not it being `subplot`ted into a figure.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala Yes I do please.  I'd like to be able to reconstruct your problem and solve it.

Comment: updated :) Anything else you need? I'll be refreshing this page ever 2 - 3 minutes

Comment: Ahhh.... you were doing the filtering on the magnitude component only.  The phase is non-existent.  That's why you're getting garbage.  Let me confirm and I'll update my answer.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala Hope my updated answer is better for you now :) Good luck!

Comment: just tried a circular notch filter and I can confirm that the image is a lot less streaky!

Comment: @SharanDuggirala I expected that.  Using a circular filters out harmonics of that frequency where the circle is centred more evenly.  Using a square will not cleanly remove the harmonics seen at those frequencies so you will still see some residual "streaking" as a side-effect.  Nice work!

Comment: I have also noticed that SO does not have the best coverage on selecting a circle of elements from a given element wihina matrix. What exactly is our policy on info coverage between Matlab Central and SO? Because Matlab Central has the answer but SO does not (at least to my knowledge)

Comment: @SharanDuggirala They're completely separate entities.  SO doesn't communicate with MATLAB Central and vice-versa.  If you want, you can add the code in to filter with circular notch filters in your post to make things complete.  I'd say that's a good way to attract more readers and more upvotes.  BTW, You have 5 upvotes now (not including the -1).  See?

Comment: very very true, I'd attribute it to the way you edited my question though. I guess it's all about asking the question in the right way. I'll make sure to add the code tomorrow. Should the extra code go onto the question or your answer?

Comment: @SharanDuggirala Yeah, I've been around for a while to know how to format a question that's more "palatable" to readers :).  You did ask a good question though.. it just needed to be slightly reformatted differently.  In any case, place it in your question... just the circular definition part.  I'll update my answer to use that code and produce another filtered image :)