# Removal of horizontal stripes using openCV2

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, fft

[image: sample image]

I am new to openCV and I was wondering if there is a way to remove the periodic stripes in the lower half of this image.

I looked at this post but couldn't quite understand what was going on: [Removing periodic noise from an image using the Fourier Transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027840/removing-periodic-noise-from-an-image-using-the-fourier-transform)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to mitigate (reduce, but not totally eliminate) the lines using Fourier Transform and notch filtering processing with Python/OpenCV/Numpy. Since the horizontal lines in the input are very close, there will be horizontal linear structures spaced far apart in the Fourier Transform spectrum. So what I did was:

- Read the input
- Pad with the mean value to powers of 2 size (to try to mitigate any ringing from the discontinuity with the padding)
- Do the DFT
- Compute the spectrum image from the magnitude
- Threshold the image and draw a black horizontal line through the center to blank out the bright DC component
- Find where the bright spots (lines) show.
- Get the coordinates of the bright spots and draw white horizontal lines on the thresholded image to form a mask
- Apply the mask to the magnitude image
- Do the IDFT
- Crop back to the size and normalize to the same dynamic range as the original image

Input:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math

# read input as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('pattern_lines.png', 0)
hh, ww = img.shape

# get min and max and mean values of img
img_min = np.amin(img)
img_max = np.amax(img)
img_mean = int(np.mean(img))

# pad the image to dimension a power of 2
hhh = math.ceil(math.log2(hh))
hhh = int(math.pow(2,hhh))
www = math.ceil(math.log2(ww))
www = int(math.pow(2,www))
imgp = np.full((hhh,www), img_mean, dtype=np.uint8)
imgp[0:hh, 0:ww] = img

# convert image to floats and do dft saving as complex output
dft = cv2.dft(np.float32(imgp), flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)

# apply shift of origin from upper left corner to center of image
dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)

# extract magnitude and phase images
mag, phase = cv2.cartToPolar(dft_shift[:,:,0], dft_shift[:,:,1])

# get spectrum
spec = np.log(mag) / 20
min, max = np.amin(spec, (0,1)), np.amax(spec, (0,1))

# threshold the spectrum to find bright spots
thresh = (255*spec).astype(np.uint8)
thresh = cv2.threshold(thresh, 155, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# cover the center rows of thresh with black
yc = hhh // 2
cv2.line(thresh, (0,yc), (www-1,yc), 0, 5)

# get the y coordinates of the bright spots
points = np.column_stack(np.nonzero(thresh))
print(points)

# create mask from spectrum drawing horizontal lines at bright spots
mask = thresh.copy()
for p in points:
    y = p[0]
    cv2.line(mask, (0,y), (www-1,y), 255, 5)

# apply mask to magnitude such that magnitude is made black where mask is white
mag[mask!=0] = 0

# convert new magnitude and old phase into cartesian real and imaginary components
real, imag = cv2.polarToCart(mag, phase)

# combine cartesian components into one complex image
back = cv2.merge([real, imag])

# shift origin from center to upper left corner
back_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(back)

# do idft saving as complex output
img_back = cv2.idft(back_ishift)

# combine complex components into original image again
img_back = cv2.magnitude(img_back[:,:,0], img_back[:,:,1])

# crop to original size
img_back = img_back[0:hh, 0:ww]

# re-normalize to 8-bits in range of original
min, max = np.amin(img_back, (0,1)), np.amax(img_back, (0,1))
notched = cv2.normalize(img_back, None, alpha=img_min, beta=img_max, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)

cv2.imshow("ORIGINAL", img)
cv2.imshow("PADDED", imgp)
cv2.imshow("MAG", mag)
cv2.imshow("PHASE", phase)
cv2.imshow("SPECTRUM", spec)
cv2.imshow("THRESH", thresh)
cv2.imshow("MASK", mask)
cv2.imshow("NOTCHED", notched)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("pattern_lines_spectrum.png", (255*spec).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8))
cv2.imwrite("pattern_lines_thresh.png", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("pattern_lines_mask.png", mask)
cv2.imwrite("pattern_lines_notched.png", notched)
```

Spectrum (note the bright spots in the middle at y=64 and 192):

[image]

Threshold Image:

[image]

Bright Spot Locations:

```
[[   0 1023]
 [   0 1024]
 [   0 1025]
 [   1 1024]
 [  64 1024]
 [  65 1024]
 [ 191 1024]
 [ 192 1024]
 [ 255 1024]]
```

Mask:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! There is however one part I don't fully understand. Why is the second step: "Pad with the mean value to powers of 2 size (to try to mitigate any ringing from the discontinuity with the padding)" necessary? I don't fully understand the use and or working of this step.

Comment: Fourier transform treats the image as if it were wrapped around in both x and y. So the left side touches the right side and the top side touches the bottom side. If there is a discontinuity in color or grayscale, then that causes a "ringing" effect of ripples -- a type of aliasing. By padding with the a common value, the opposite sides match in color. By using the mean value, it is hoped that the mean is close to the color of all sides. See Gibbs phenomenon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringing_artifacts. The other fact is that the Fourier transform runs faster if power of two.

Comment: See also https://docs.opencv.org/master/de/dbc/tutorial_py_fourier_transform.html

Comment: Hi again, recently I encountered a problem. Some of the images I'm processing don't have the desired outcome. They look like this: https://imgur.com/WkI5ecj

Comment: Please give more details. What was the starting image? What was wrong? Post another question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61738477/fourier-analysis-of-tiff-images-using-opencv  I have posted a new question, thanks in advance!