# Fourier analysis of tiff images using openCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, fft

## Image Loading

To start I tried loading in .tif images using openCV but got the following error: Invalid bitsperpixel value read from TIFF header! Must be 1, 8, 16, 32 or 64. in function 'cv::TiffDecoder::readHeader'

Checked using a hex editor to determine the bit depth of the image and it seems to be 16bit.

[image: tif file contents]

After some trail and error I managed to find a solution using the code below.
First loaded the image with the specialized tifffile library. Then saved it to a temporary file and finally loaded it back in again with openCV. (Directly trying to edit the image read from Tifffile using openCV functions didn't work)

```
raw_image = tifffile.imread(file)
raw_image <<= 4
name = random_string(10) + '.tif'
tifffile.imwrite(name, raw_image)
image = cv2.imread(file, 0)
os.remove(name)
```

[image: image without any processing, succesfully loaded]

## Processing

As the purpose of my program is to detect and track the droplets present on the image, the periodic stripe pattern/interference makes the tracking algorithm struggle. In a previous question a solution was proposed and initially gave promising results: [Removal of horizontal stripes using openCV2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60506244/removal-of-horizontal-stripes-using-opencv2)

Now after some more testing I'm getting the following result:

[image]

Succes depends on the files used.

The following link contains a folder with images it does work on and one with images it doesn't work on. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ifsae0bl2CRoR2ydlQlf35FlzagmeryL/view?usp=sharing

Something worth mentioning is that this processing is done on a large set of images (+-5000). To speed things up I used multiprocessing as implemented below.

```
 with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
            results = executor.map(self.process_image, file_list)
            for result in results:
                self.image_array.append(result)

    def process_image(self, file):
    try:
        # first the image is read by the tifffile library because openCV can't interpret the
        # proprietary bit depth of the provided images. All the bits of the image are shifted
        # to acquire an image with the right bit depth. A temporary file with a randomly generated
        # name is created because openCV couldn't directly open the shifted image directly.

        raw_image = tifffile.imread(file)
        raw_image <<= 4
        name = random_string(10) + '.tif'
        tifffile.imwrite(name, raw_image)
        image = cv2.imread(name, 0)
        os.remove(name)

        cv2.imshow('test', image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

        # removal of periodic interference
        image = self.remove_periodic_interference(image)

        cv2.imshow('test', image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

        # application of mask
        image = self.aplly_mask(image)

        cv2.imshow('test', image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

        # image now ready for droplet detection
        return image
    except cv2.error as e:
        print(e, 'check if the image files are present')

# removal of periodic stripe pattern in the lower half of the provided image
# using fourier analysis (fft = fast fourier transformation)
def remove_periodic_interference(self, img):
    hh, ww = img.shape

    # get min and max and mean values of img
    img_min = np.amin(img)
    img_max = np.amax(img)
    img_mean = int(np.mean(img))

    # pad the image to dimension a power of 2
    hhh = math.ceil(math.log2(hh))
    hhh = int(math.pow(2, hhh))
    www = math.ceil(math.log2(ww))
    www = int(math.pow(2, www))
    imgp = np.full((hhh, www), img_mean, dtype=np.uint8)
    imgp[0:hh, 0:ww] = img

    # convert image to floats and do dft saving as complex output
    dft = cv2.dft(np.float32(imgp), flags=cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)

    # apply shift of origin from upper left corner to center of image
    dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)

    # extract magnitude and phase images
    mag, phase = cv2.cartToPolar(dft_shift[:, :, 0], dft_shift[:, :, 1])

    # get spectrum
    spec = np.log(mag) / 20
    min, max = np.amin(spec, (0, 1)), np.amax(spec, (0, 1))

    # threshold the spectrum to find bright spots
    thresh = (255 * spec).astype(np.uint8)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(thresh, 155, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    # cover the center rows of thresh with black
    yc = hhh // 2
    cv2.line(thresh, (0, yc), (www - 1, yc), 0, 5)

    # get the y coordinates of the bright spots
    points = np.column_stack(np.nonzero(thresh))
    print(points)

    # create mask from spectrum drawing horizontal lines at bright spots
    mask = thresh.copy()
    for p in points:
        y = p[0]
        cv2.line(mask, (0, y), (www - 1, y), 255, 5)

    # apply mask to magnitude such that magnitude is made black where mask is white
    mag[mask != 0] = 0

    # convert new magnitude and old phase into cartesian real and imaginary components
    real, imag = cv2.polarToCart(mag, phase)

    # combine cartesian components into one complex image
    back = cv2.merge([real, imag])

    # shift origin from center to upper left corner
    back_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(back)

    # do idft saving as complex output
    img_back = cv2.idft(back_ishift)

    # combine complex components into original image again
    img_back = cv2.magnitude(img_back[:, :, 0], img_back[:, :, 1])

    # crop to original size
    img_back = img_back[0:hh, 0:ww]

    # re-normalize to 8-bits in range of original
    min, max = np.amin(img_back, (0, 1)), np.amax(img_back, (0, 1))
    notched = cv2.normalize(img_back, None, alpha=img_min, beta=img_max, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)

    return notched

# application of mask to isolate the usable 'droplets' from each image
# TODO-- optimization --
# TODO-- adjust offset--
def aplly_mask(self, image):
    th, threshed = cv2.threshold(image, 116, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C | cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C)

    # Find the min-area contour
    cnts = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, offset=(1, 1))[-2]
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

    # Manual scaling of contours
    for c in cnts:

        M = cv2.moments(c)

        if M["m00"] != 0:
            cx = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
            cy = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
        else:
            cx, cy = 0, 0

        scale = 1.5

        cnt_norm = c - [cx, cy]
        cnt_scaled = cnt_norm * scale
        cnt_scaled = cnt_scaled + [cx, cy]
        cnt_scaled = cnt_scaled.astype(np.int32)

    # Mask application
    mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], np.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(mask, cnts, -1, 255, -1)
    dst = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
    dst = cv2.bitwise_not(dst, dst)

    return dst
```

Comment: Have you looked at the spectrum image to see that it has the spots as in your first post and that your mask is being generated appropriately. If there are not good bright spots that are easily isolated, then your threshold may either need adjusting or the image is not appropriate for this method.

Comment: There' s no need for the little dance with `tifffile` and **OpenCV** by the way. Just use `image = tifffile.imread('matrix.tif') << 4` and run with that - no need to write to disk and re-read.

Comment: @MarkSetchell when using this method, the image turns out like this after applying the fourrier tansform: https://imgur.com/IC4iqmM

Comment: Oh, I see what's happening. OpenCV is converting it to `uint8` because of the `0` on your `cv2.imread(...,0)`. So, you should be able to use `image = (tifffile.imread('matrix.tif') >>4).astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: Thanks a lott! This did work and greatly improved the performance of image loading.

Comment: @fmw42 in the treshold image I noticed some extra dot's in the middle, might these be the cause of the distortion? https://imgur.com/a/rKNIFEu

Comment: @fmw42 managed to fix it by drawing a black rectangle on the center 4 white stopts on the treshold image.