# Image Processing: Removing cyclic interferrence noise from photo

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, line, fft

Here you can see the original image of a Schlieren image from an experiment with a very old camera system. I'm trying to remove these progressive lines using opencv in python but without any luck. Images are cropped due to NDAs.

PS: I'm an aerodynamicist. I have no prior knowledge of image processing.

[Original Cropped Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1cbL.png)

Here is the code i am using:

```
img = cv2.imread(str(img_dir), 0)
median = cv2.medianBlur(img, 1)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(median, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
```

As you could see i used a combination of blurring and morphology. This is the best result I have, it preserved the flow features but there are various ugly lines near the model. I have several images exactly with the same problem and it cant be fixed within the experiment. So i thought i give image processing a try.

Things i tried:

1. detect the vertical lines using Sobel

- mask the Sobel vertical lines
- using inpaint to "paint" over the lines

2. Observing the frequency domain by FFTing the image

- using ([Removing periodic noise from an image using the Fourier Transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027840/removing-periodic-noise-from-an-image-using-the-fourier-transform))
- the low and high pass filter ended up filtering out all of the flow field.

[Processed Image: Using Morphology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19d6e.png)